# Как переместить ссылки?

Tags: php

Есть две ссылки:

```
<?php if(isset($products2) && is_array($products2) && count($products2)>0) { ?>
                    <div class="col col6"><a href="#" class="change">Спецпредложения</a></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col col5"><a data-fancybox="modal_ofert" data-src="#modal_opt3" href="javascript:;"><img src="/image/portal-zakypok.png" title="О компании" alt="О компании" class="menu_about_img"> Запросить оферту</a></div>
```

Нужно поменять местами "Запросить оферту" и "Спецпредложения". Просто переместить не вариант, тогда перестает работать скрипт. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: что значит перестает работать? нечему тут переставать работать, эти два блока друг на друга не влияют никак

Comment: @teran если их просто поменять местами, то кнопка спецпредложения становится неактивной

Comment: Значит чините скрипт, очевидно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если родителю присвоено свойство display:flex,то элементарно:

```css
.flex{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
.col6{order:1}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="col col6"><a href="#" class="change">Спецпредложения</a></div>
    <div class="col col5">
        <a data-fancybox="modal_ofert" data-src="#modal_opt3" href="javascript:;"><img src="/image/portal-zakypok.png" title="" alt="" class="menu_about_img"> Запросить оферту</a>
    </div>
</div>
```